# Open Panel (files / folders) and Insert a File at Cursor Position

Tags: emacs

I'm looking for a way to open the panel (directory tree) of files / folders in Emacs on an OSX operating system and select any file from the list to be inserted at the cursor position in the current buffer.  C-x i requires that I know the name of the exact name / path of the file, which means I have to first visit that file, open it up and run the determine path/file name function, then copy that path / filename and return to the original buffer and then run C-x i, delete the sample path that is there, and paste the correct path / filename and hit return.  Alternatively, I'd have to use another program to get the filename / path and then do the same final steps.

I ending up writing my own plugin for Sublime Text 2 using the python `open(self.template_path).read()`, however, that took a couple of days for me to figure out.  Does anyone know of `defun` example that will open the panel (of folders / files) to insert a file at the cursor position, or perhaps something similar to the python open.read example that can be modified to insert a file by opening the panel?

[image: insert_file]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/insert_file.png))</sub>

Comment: `C-x i` has filename completion. Which means you can use the exact same keystrokes to insert a file as to visit it with `C-x C-f`. No need to visit it first.

Comment: I'm looking for an open-panel option, please, that displays a directory of all folders / files anywhere on the computer.  Once the directory tree of folders / files is open, the user can navigate with the arrow keys to select the file.  Emacs built from source `--with-ns` on OSX has the ability to open and save files by navigating the directory tree of folders / files.  I'd like to create the equivalent for insert file -- I have way too many folders and files to try to guess the name or use auto-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
(defun insert-file-from-osx-panel ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((file-name (ns-read-file-name "Select File to Insert" nil t)))
    (and file-name (insert-file file-name))))
```

?